# Return value of non-initialized reference_wrapper

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, reference-wrapper

Where does `reference_wrapper` point to when I `resize()` the vector below? Is this an undefined behavior? What should I do for safety?

```
std::vector < std::reference_wrapper <int> > vec;
vec.resize(10);
```

Comment: It seems that you can't resize `vec`. You can only `push_back` to add more items to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code doesn't compile, because `reference_wrapper` doesn't have a default constructor.

> ```
> error: no matching function for call to ‘std::reference_wrapper<int>::reference_wrapper()’
> ```

Answer (score 1):

`vector<T>::resize(size_type)` requires that the `T` be default constructible, and [`reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/reference_wrapper) isn't, so your code doesn't compile as is.

But presumably, you're asking what happens to the `reference_wrapper` objects when the `vector` reallocates storage as necessary. Nothing special, they will continue referring to the object they were originally referring to.

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f7e2674fc6e2689)